# C: Const array pointer to modifiable array size

Tags: c, arrays

I have a constant array pointer and its size like this:

```
        const UInt8* raw_addr = ujArrayRawAccessStart(addr);
        UInt8 addr_len = ujArrayLen(addr);
```

And I need to add something to the end of this array, the '\0' because in reality we are working with strings and code further down the line requires this.
To do so, I was thinking of initializing a new array like this:

```
            UInt8 formatted_addr[sizeof(raw_addr)/sizeof(raw_addr[0]) + sizeof('\0')];
        for(int i = 0; i< addr_len; i++){
            formatted_addr[i] = raw_addr[i];
        }
        formatted_addr[addr_len]='\0';  //string literal needs to end with \0
```

However, this causes my node on which the node is running to freak out (its UART output is malformed), indicating I'm writing somewhere where I shouldn't.

What am I doing wrong, or are there better ways to achieve what I want?

Comment: `UInt8 formatted_addr[sizeof(raw_addr)/sizeof(raw_addr[0]) + sizeof('\0')];` --> `UInt8 formatted_addr[addr_len+ 1];`

Comment: BTW: `sizeof ('\0')` == `sizeof 0` in C. You probably just want `1`

Comment: @joop `sizeof ('\0')` is `sizeof (int)` and so it is probably `2` or `4` and not `1`.

Comment: That's what I wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sizeof(raw_addr)` is the size of a pointer! (`UInt8*`). Not (informally) the size of the array it points to.<sup>1</sup>

So your `formatted_addr` is always going to be of the same size, irregardless of the actual size of what `raw_addr` points to.

The `sizeof(array)/sizeof(elem)` trick only works for actual arrays. I.e `Type[N]`

If `addr_len` isn't too big and your implementation permits (see [`__STDC_NO_VLA__`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor/replace)
 ), you can just declare a [variable-length array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array):

```
formatted_addr[addr_len + 1];
```

Otherwise, only dynamic memory allocation is how it can be done.

---

<sup>1</sup>  It's just a pointer to the first element in a memory block that happens to hold several consecutive elements. Not an array from a type system perspective.

Comment: ... but to the array's 1st element.